# How to handle one Stored Procedure output (ResultSet or Table) into another Stored Procedure as Table

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

one Stored Procedure is returning me a table and I want to hold that result into another Stored Procedure.
and I am facing SQL syntax error.

First Stored Procedure

```
DELIMITER $$
USE `dataBase`$$
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `testReturnTable`$$
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `testReturnTable`()
BEGIN
    SELECT `user_id`, `email` FROM `users`;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

and I am trying to call this Store Procedure into another and want to hold the data into a view or table

```
DELIMITER $$
USE `dataBase`$$
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `testReturnCall`$$
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `testReturnCall`()
BEGIN
    DROP VIEW IF EXISTS `my_view`;
    CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW my_view AS (CALL testReturnTable());
    SELECT * FROM my_view;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

and getting error

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'CALL testReturnTable());
```

I can use function here as well, but I don't know how to handle result set,
please advice.

Comment: I found one solution to do this, but its not working at my end, 
https://forums.mysql.com/read.php?118,240489,267291

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is not possible to get table ouput from one stored procedure to another stored procedure. But we have alternate to do this which is Temp table

Comment: _"But we have alternate to do this which is Temp table"_ it would be great if you [edit] your answer and post that _alternate_

Comment: Yes, Thanks for your suggestion, I tried to create a table and insert values into that table from one sp and get data from the same table in another sp. and its work for me

Comment: @Shashanth, you can just create one more table to handle data and then just save data into it for next use. but you are suppose to keep one more parameter into that table, for identify the records relations.